# Using methods from github

Tags: contract-deployment, abstract

Is it possible too return value in this way?
This is for an understanding of the mechanism of using a method from github
Thank you!

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

abstract contract Token is ERC20 {
      uint8 returnValueFromExt;
 
      
      ERC20 extBase;


      function testCall() public view returns(uint){
          return extBase.decimals();
          // returnValueFromExt = extBase.decimals();
      }
}
```

After deploying, I receive this error.

> This contract may be abstract, it may not implement an abstract
> parent's methods completely or it may not invoke an inherited
> contract's constructor correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Token` contract **is** an `ERC20` token and can directly call the `decimals()` function
You can remove the `abstract` keyword from the contract declaration as is not necessary

If you want to call an external `decimals()` function, your `extBase` variable, which is an address should be equal to an existing ERC20 token.

For example, if `extBase` is set to the address of Token B and your current contract is Token A, you can call the `decimals()` function as follows:

```
function testCall() public view returns (uint) {
    return extBase.decimals();
}
```

If you want to test with any ERC20 token address, you can use the following function:

```
function testCall(address extToken) public view returns (uint) {
    return ERC20(extToken).decimals();
}
```

Comment: thank you i will dive deeply in this explenations

Comment: unfortunately it still doest work

Comment: it ask me for abstract

Comment: during deploy throw this error -> This contract may be abstract, it may not implement an abstract parent's methods completely or it may not invoke an inherited contract's constructor correctly.

Comment: error without abstract -> from solidity:
TypeError: Contract "Token" should be marked as abstract.

Comment: you need a `constructor`